# Substitute for Thread.Suspend -Resume without performance loss

Tags: multithreading, delphi, graphics

I'm working on a slideshow with transition- zooming -panning -effects with performance being critical for smooth rendering. This is an old project which I'm porting to Delphi 10.3, with a thread to load the next slide from a file-stream of jpgeg-images while the rendering to screen is running. In my old code the thread was continuously running being suspended and resumed as necessary. Here's the flow of the old now deprecated code:

```
procedure TSlideshow.Create;
begin
  MakeNextThread:=TMakenextThread.Create(true);
  MakeNextThread.FreeOnTerminate:=false;
end;

procedure TSlideshow.Render(previous, next: integer);
begin
  //Check if thread has loaded next, if not make it here

  //Send off the thread to make next+1
  //The next block takes less than 0.1 ms on average !!!
  If next+1 < count then
  begin
    //Fill fields of MakeNextThread with data to load next+1
    MakeNextThread.Resume;
  end;

  //Render to screen
end;

procedure TMakeNextThread.Execute;
begin
  while not terminated do
  begin
    //Load bitmap from jpeg-stream
    sleep(1)
    //Prepare alpha-channel for transition
    done:=true;
    suspend;
  end;
end;
```

This is my attempt to avoid the use of suspend and resume, but the result is unacceptable, as it causes the slideshow to pause noticably before the transition.

```
procedure TSlideshow.Render(previous, next: integer);
begin
  //Check if thread has loaded next, if not make it here

  //Send off the thread to make next+1
  //The next block takes more than 40 ms on average !!!
  If next+1 < count then
  begin
    MakeNextThread.terminate;
    MakeNextThread.free;
    MakeNextThread:=TMakeNextThread.Create(true);
    MakeNextThread.FreeOnTerminate:=false;
    //Fill fields of MakeNextThread with data to load next+1
    MakeNextThread.Start;
  end;

  //Render to screen
end;

procedure TMakeNextThread.Execute;
begin
  //Load bitmap from jpeg-stream
  sleep(1)
  //Prepare alpha-channel for transition
    done:=true;
end;
```

Is there a way to do this without the performance penalty? And what is so dangerous about using suspend resume in the first place?

Comment: Suspending a thread from the outside may deadlock it. A better approach is to query the thread to do it itself - just like Remy answered, where `WaitFor()` is the suspension and `TEvent` the resuming.

Comment: Delphi's TTHread.Suspend basically calls the Windows SuspendThread function. About why it is not a good idea to use SuspendThread in most circumstances Raimond Chen has a good explanation here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150205-00/?p=44743

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to make a whole new thread each time. Just use a `TEvent` object inside of `TMakeNextThread`. Make `Execute()` run a loop that calls `TEvent.WaitFor()`, and then you can call `TEvent.SetEvent()` when you want to "wake up" the thread, and `TEvent.ResetEvent()` when you want to "suspend" the thread.  When the event is signaled and `Terminated` is False, the loop can do its work.

Comment: The event is ideally named `Run` or `WakeUp` to remind you why you trigger it.